# Stuck photos while inside an envelope

Tags: stationery, photography

It seems the photos have been stuck to each other. I had kept them inside the envelope which was given when I purchased those photos. It's been about 5 months since I had last opened that envelope. And now today I need them and they are stuck to each other.

**What can I do to separate them?**

[image: Image of photos stuck together]

Comment: I haven't tried any wierd things. As i don't want to spoil those photos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they are gelatin-emulsion based, as used in traditional photography (or some coated ink-jet papers), hold the back side of the pack over a steaming kettle and let the steam slowly loosen the rear-most photo, one at a time. Just set them aside to dry *separately* afterwards.

**N.B. Ink jet photos might 'run' in water. Test this on one photo to see if it damages it.**

Comment: Yes that did separate them.