# unstick stuck photos

Tags: cleaning, stationery

My question is like [this one](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/14152/stuck-photos-while-inside-an-envolope), but only more so.  My photos have been in the envelope for more than 30 years.  I tried water, then steam, then turpentine, none of which worked.
These are BW silver oxide photos on Kodak paper.  Any ideas?

Comment: When you say you tried water, for how long?  They will need to be soaked in a bath of water at least overnight.

Comment: @Chenmunka That should be a supported answer.

Comment: It's a little late to say this, but scan them before you try anything. I found this out the hard way.

Comment: Yes, well, we have strayed into a logical impossibility.  I can't scan them until I've separated them, but before I separate them I should scan them.  It is more than my poor brain can cope with, sahib.

Answer (score 3):

A similar question has a full and detailed answer over on [Photo.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/).

This [post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/50398/61147) states that you need to keep the pictures humid for an extended period.

In my experience, soaking the photos in a bath or water for at least 12 hours will separate them.  The pictures can then be carefully dried after you have carefully peeled them apart.

Comment: Yes, I have tried 12 hours.  However, since I now see that 12 hours is roughly right, not 'way too high, I'll try a week, since, as I say, they've been stuck together now for decades.

Comment: Yes, a week did it.  I never expected it to take so long, but they are now cleanly separate.  Thanks to the net and all you experts for the right answer.Now on to the next problem: flattening.